# Calcular média somente nos campos digitados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, estou programando um sistema no qual calcula a média de alguns campos. A questão é que nem sempre todas os valores serão informados e a média deve calcular os campos nos quais existem valores, ou seja, o cálculo da média vai variar de acordo com os campos ontem tem valor.

**HTML**

```
<form name="formMediasETEs" method="post" action="AdicionarVazao.php">
    <tr class="tabela_dados">
        <td>
            <input name="data" style="text-align:center; width:150px" style="font-size:10px" type="date" id="data" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="oito" type="text" id="oito" onblur="ver()" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="nove" type="text" id="nove" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="dez" type="text" id="dez" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="onze" type="text" id="onze" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="doze" type="text" id="doze" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="treze" type="text" id="treze" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="quatorze" type="text" id="quatorze" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="quinze" type="text" id="quinze" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="d_seis" type="text" id="d_seis" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="d_sete" type="text" id="d_sete" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="d_oito" type="text" onblur="calcularMediaQLSETES()" id="d_oito" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function calcularMediaQLSETES() {
    var q2 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['oito'].value;
    var q3 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['nove'].value;
    var q4 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['dez'].value;
    var q5 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['onze'].value;
    var q23 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['doze'].value;
    var q6 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['treze'].value;
    var q7 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['quatorze'].value;
    var q8 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['quinze'].value;
    var q9 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['d_seis'].value;
    var q10 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['d_sete'].value;
    var q11 = document.forms['formMediasETEs']['d_oito'].value;

    var mqls = (parseFloat(q2) + parseFloat(q3) + parseFloat(q4) +
        parseFloat(q5) + parseFloat(q23) + parseFloat(q6) + parseFloat(q7) +
        parseFloat(q8) + parseFloat(q9) + parseFloat(q10) + parseFloat(q11)) / 11;

    document.forms['formMediasETEs']['mediaQ_ls'].value = mqls.toFixed(2);
}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Tudo bem se a solução for com jQuery e não apenas com JavaScript?

Comment: Sim, pode ser! Obrigado

Comment: Se puder, coloque na pergunta também como o HTML está montado, pode ser somente a parte do formulário. Isso vai ajudar o pessoal em montar soluções mais elaboradas, as vezes o "problema" não é somente no JS. Eu vejo que isso ai pode ser melhorado com um looping, removendo esse monte de variáveis, mas precisaria saber como o HTML está sendo criado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segue um POC com jQuery, acredito que deva ajudar:

HTML:

```
Nota 1: <input class="nota" /><br/>
Nota 2: <input class="nota" /><br/>
Nota 3: <input class="nota" /><br/><br/>
Media: <input id="media" readonly/>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    $('.nota').change(function(){
      var total = 0;
      var notas = 0;
      $('.nota').each(function(){
          var nota = new Number(this.value);          
          if(nota === 0) return;          
          total = total + nota;
          notas++;
      })
      $('#media').val(total/notas);
  });
})
```

Veja funcionando no [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y0qzyv09/).

Comment: Tem um problema, amigo. Por causa do new Number, a comparação de igualdade nunca será verdadeira.
Se tirar o new o problema já se resolve. ;)

Comment: Perfeito, resolvido! Era isso que eu precisava. Obrigado à todos!

Answer (score 5):

Utilizando somente [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) você precisaria apenas obter os valores dos `inputs` e verificar se os mesmos possuem valor. Caso possua, basta somar normalmente e incrementar a quantidade a ser calculada.

Ficaria desta forma:

```html
<script>
  function calcularMedia(){
    //Você pode alterar o elemento de acordo com a sua necessidade
    inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
    var quantidade = 0;
    var total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
      var valor = parseInt(inputs[i].value);
      if(valor){
            total = total + valor;
            quantidade ++;
      }
   }
    var media = total / quantidade;
    
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML  = "Media: " + media;
  }
</script>

<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="text"/><br/>
<input type="text"/><br/>

<button  onclick="calcularMedia()">Calcular</button>

<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não aconselho usar o jQuery apenas para fazer esse tipo de calculo simples, exceto se você já utilizar ele para outras funções mais complexas.

```js
function calcularMediaQLSETES()  
{  
  var formMedia = document.forms['formMediasETEs'];
  var total = 12; //numero total de campos
  values = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++ ){ //começo em 1 porque 0 é a data
     let actual = parseInt(formMedia[i].value);
     if(!actual){
        total--;
        continue;
     }
     values += actual;
  }
  return !alert(values/total);
}
```

```html
<form name="formMediasETEs" method="post" action="AdicionarVazao.php">
<tr>
    <td><input name="data" style="text-align:center; width:150px" style="font-size:10px" type="date" id="data" value=""/></td>
    <td><input name="oito" type="text" id="oito" onblur="ver()" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value=""/></td>
    <td><input name="nove" type="text" id="nove" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value=""/></td>
    <td><input name="dez" type="text" id="dez" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value=""/></td>
    <td><input name="onze" type="text" id="onze" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value=""/></td>
    <td><input name="doze" type="text" id="doze" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value=""/></td>
    <td><input name="treze" type="text" id="treze" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value=""/></td>
    <td><input name="quatorze" type="text" id="quatorze" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value=""/></td>
    <td><input name="quinze" type="text" id="quinze" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value=""/></td>
    <td><input name="d_seis" type="text" id="d_seis" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value=""/></td>
    <td><input name="d_sete" type="text" id="d_sete" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value=""/></td>
    <td><input name="d_oito" type="text" onblur="calcularMediaQLSETES()" id="d_oito" style="text-align:center; width: 60px" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<br><br>
<input onClick="calcularMediaQLSETES()" type="button" value="Calcular Media" />
</form>
```